Catch exception raised in foreachBatch function
I'm working on Databricks with Pyspark Structured Streaming and would like to catch a exception raised by myself within the function passed as '.foreachBatch'-function to the stream.
This is my example code:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType
from delta.tables import DeltaTable
from pyspark.sql.streaming import StreamingQueryException

table_location = "hive_metastore.default.test_example"
checkpoint_location = "/tmp/test_checkpoint"

schema = StructType([
    StructField("BestellID", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("CRDAT", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Menge", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("__cmi_ingestion_ts", StringType(), True)
])

data = [(1, '20240901', 3, '20241002')]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable(table_location)

deltaTable = DeltaTable.forName(spark, table_location)

def mergetoDF(df, batchID):
    raise ValueError("This is an error")

def test_run():

    try:
        inbound_data = (spark.readStream.format("delta").table(table_location))

        streamQuery = (inbound_data                           
                    .writeStream
                    .format("delta")
                    .outputMode("append")
                    .foreachBatch(mergetoDF)
                    .trigger(once=True)
                    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_location)
                    .start()
                )
        streamQuery.awaitTermination()
    except ValueError:
        print('I am a value error')
    except StreamingQueryException as e:
        if 'FOREACH_BATCH_USER_FUNCTION_ERROR' in str(e):
            print('I am a StreamingQueryException')

test_run()

I would like to be able to catch errors raised inside 'foreachBatch'-function without any additional error messages printed to screen. But currently, a StreamingQueryException is caught and additional error telling
ERROR: Some streams terminated before this command could finish!
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Found error inside foreachBatch Python process: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File &quot;/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/streaming/worker/foreach_batch_worker.py&quot;, line 99, in main
    process(df_ref_id, int(batch_id))
  File &quot;/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/connect/streaming/worker/foreach_batch_worker.py&quot;, line 86, in process
    func(batch_df, batch_id)
  File &quot;/home/spark-19129aeb-c024-45c4-ac47-ef/.ipykernel/54200/command-3034895255467445-2795320295&quot;, line 7, in mergetoDF
ValueError: This is an error

    at org.apache.spark.sql.connect.planner.StreamingForeachBatchHelper$.$anonfun$pythonForeachBatchWrapper$6(StreamingForeachBatchHelper.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connect.planner.StreamingForeachBatchHelper$.$anonfun$pythonForeachBatchWrapper$6$adapted(StreamingForeachBatchHelper.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connect.planner.StreamingForeachBatchHelper$.$anonfun$dataFrameCachingWrapper$1(StreamingForeachBatchHelper.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connect.planner.StreamingForeachBatchHelper$.$anonfun$dataFrameCachingWrapper$1$adapted(StreamingForeachBatchHelper.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachBatchSink.callBatchWriter(ForeachBatchSink.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachBatchSink.$anonfun$addBatchOptimized$2(ForeachBatchSink.scala:247)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachBatchSink.runWithAQE(ForeachBatchSink.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachBatchSink.addBatchOptimized(ForeachBatchSink.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachBatchSink.$anonfun$addBatch$2(ForeachBatchSink.scala:99)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:537)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachBatchSink.addBatch(ForeachBatchSink.scala:91)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.addBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:1238)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$18(MicroBatchExecution.scala:1456)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressContext.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.markAndTimeCollectBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:1246)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$17(MicroBatchExecution.scala:1456)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId0$10(SQLExecution.scala:462)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:800)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId0$1(SQLExecution.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:1180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId0(SQLExecution.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:1449)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressContext.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:1449)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$executeOneBatch$6(MicroBatchExecution.scala:760)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.handleDataSourceException(MicroBatchExecution.scala:1868)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$executeOneBatch$5(MicroBatchExecution.scala:760)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.withSchemaEvolution(MicroBatchExecution.scala:1813)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$executeOneBatch$4(MicroBatchExecution.scala:756)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressContext.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$executeOneBatch$3(MicroBatchExecution.scala:716)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContextTracing.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(AttributionContextTracing.scala:48)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext$.$anonfun$withValue$1(AttributionContext.scala:276)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext$.withValue(AttributionContext.scala:272)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContextTracing.withAttributionContext(AttributionContextTracing.scala:46)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContextTracing.withAttributionContext$(AttributionContextTracing.scala:43)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionContext(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:27)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContextTracing.withAttributionTags(AttributionContextTracing.scala:95)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContextTracing.withAttributionTags$(AttributionContextTracing.scala:76)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:27)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags0(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:74)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:175)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionTags$1(UsageLogger.scala:617)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging$.withAttributionTags(UsageLogger.scala:729)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging$.withAttributionTags(UsageLogger.scala:738)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogger.scala:617)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogger.scala:615)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.withAttributionTags(StreamExecution.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.executeOneBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStreamWithListener$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:671)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStreamWithListener$1$adapted(MicroBatchExecution.scala:671)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.TriggerExecutor.runOneBatch(TriggerExecutor.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.TriggerExecutor.runOneBatch$(TriggerExecutor.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.SingleBatchExecutor.runOneBatch(TriggerExecutor.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.SingleBatchExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStreamWithListener(MicroBatchExecution.scala:671)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:448)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$2(StreamExecution.scala:454)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:1180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:401)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContextTracing.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(AttributionContextTracing.scala:48)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext$.$anonfun$withValue$1(AttributionContext.scala:276)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContext$.withValue(AttributionContext.scala:272)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContextTracing.withAttributionContext(AttributionContextTracing.scala:46)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContextTracing.withAttributionContext$(AttributionContextTracing.scala:43)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionContext(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:27)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContextTracing.withAttributionTags(AttributionContextTracing.scala:95)
    at com.databricks.logging.AttributionContextTracing.withAttributionTags$(AttributionContextTracing.scala:76)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:27)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags0(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:74)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:175)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionTags$1(UsageLogger.scala:617)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging$.withAttributionTags(UsageLogger.scala:729)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging$.withAttributionTags(UsageLogger.scala:738)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogger.scala:617)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogger.scala:615)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.withAttributionTags(StreamExecution.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.$anonfun$run$3(StreamExecution.scala:284)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.JobArtifactSet$.withActiveJobArtifactState(JobArtifactSet.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.$anonfun$run$2(StreamExecution.scala:284)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.unity.UCSEphemeralState$Handle.runWith(UCSEphemeralState.scala:51)
    at com.databricks.unity.HandleImpl.runWith(UCSHandle.scala:104)
    at com.databricks.unity.HandleImpl.$anonfun$runWithAndClose$1(UCSHandle.scala:109)
    at scala.util.Using$.resource(Using.scala:269)
    at com.databricks.unity.HandleImpl.runWithAndClose(UCSHandle.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:283)

leading to script status 'Last execution failed'.
Actually, I want to write pytest tests and expect exceptions in the tests.

Please edit the question with the error you're getting. Provide the whole traceback or at least more information. I don't understand how you get two errors at the same time. It only happens if an exception happened while catching another exception.

Thank you for trying to help me! I changed the question and posted the whole error.

You could move the try-except block into the function called by foreachBatch


.foreachBatch(mergetoDF)

AFAIK if mergetoDF() throws an exception then it'll always be propagated to main thread (one calling streamQuery.start()).
Only way to "handle" errors in code of the function passed to foreachBatch() is inside the function that you pass (mergetoDF in this case). Somewhat similar to how you would handle errors inside a UDF. So e.g. you could

write errors to some file in a shared file system. Shared across the cluster like dbfs or s3 or adls.
add a new column to the output df called errors and store the errors in it.



Actually, I want to write pytest tests and expect exceptions in the tests.

Once you move your error handling inside mergetoDF(), your tests would only test mergetoDF() for various error scenarios that produce exception.
Tests for test_run() would mock most of spark. I.e. you test your code not spark code.
